# Setting the default values of AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, assemblyinfo

What is the best way to change the default values that AssemblyInfo.cs is created with, e.g. I don't want the Microsoft bits in AssemblyCompany and AssemblyCopyright

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Microsoft")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Microsoft 2011")]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably only in registry:

```
32 bit: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
64 bit: HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion
```

[Changing the default values for AssemblyInfo.cs](http://devtogether.com/internal-notes/vs-assemblyinfo-defaults.html)

Also here is the post on SO: [How to change registration company name for Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200635/how-to-change-registration-company-name-for-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: The first links seems to be broken. Some more explanation would be great.

Comment: The first link from another source is at : http://dotnetwithme.blogspot.com/2007/04/visual-studio-tip-how-to-change-default.html

Comment: For lazy people -like me- who use a registry path opener utility, here's the correct 64-bit path: `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`.

Answer (score 12):

It appears that this info is embedded in the project template definition. For instance, if I create a project using the "Console Application" project template, it uses:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows\1033\ConsoleApplication.zip
```

Looking inside that zip file there is an AssemblyInfo.cs file which contains:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("$registeredorganization$")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("$projectname$")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © $registeredorganization$ $year$")]
```

So if you can't change the registration info of your machine like others have suggested, you could just update this file here

Comment: Thanks for the pointer ... I've used the registry tip as it's a single place to edit, rather than having to go through each of the zip files, but knowing they are there is very useful

Comment: It seems changing formatting of project template does not do anything, I rearranged year and organization but new project still uses old format.

Answer (score 3):

Little offtopic: Every project has its own assemblyinfo.cs. To keep things DRY, I'd recommend the usage of a [GlobalAssemblyInfo](http://synapticmeandering.blogspot.nl/2012/01/using-global-assemblyinfo-file.html)

Comment: I read the article in the link you provided.  A lot of words to simply suggest "Use a linked file instead of a real file."

Answer (score 0):

If you mean when you create a new VS Project it should default to your firm name, you can modify the project templates but this will need to be done on each dev machine.

If you're trying to alleviate the PITA of managing this common data in all of the assemblies in a solution you could use a SharedAssemblyInfo.cs file.  Create this at the solution level then add to all of your other projects by adding it as a linked file (the Add Dialog box has a little flyout on the button).  This approach is used commonly for assembly versioning

More info from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975763/sharedassemblyinfo-cs) also.

Answer (score 0):

As an update, I found this location and updated all the assemblyinfo.cs files for the various project types (Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10).  That seems to have worked:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Windows Root\Windows\1033